# C# - Downloading files - Only download file if local filestamp is older than on server

Tags: c#, .net, windows

How is it possible to download files from a server, and have C# only download the file if the timestamp on the local file is older than the file timestamp on the server? In this case the two files have the same name, extension, etc...

For example file in web server:

```
http://www.test.com/test.txt
```

File on local computer:

```
C:\test.txt
```

Comment: You'll have to be a bit more specific.  Where are you downloading from?  A web server, a local or remote network, ftp, ...

Comment: When you say "download" how are you accessing the file on the server, http, ftp, windows network share?

Comment: @Chris Lively A webserver e.g. http://www.test.com/test.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this link:
http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_general/internet/print.php/c16073

Basically your looking for a "conditional get"  The link above should get you started.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the **HTTP If-Modified-Since header field** to download a file only when it's newer than a given timestamp:

1. Determine the [LastWriteTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.lastwritetimeutc.aspx) the local file.
2. Send the [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8y7x3zz2.aspx) with the [IfModifiedSince](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.ifmodifiedsince.aspx) property set to the LastWriteTime.
3. If the remote file has been modified since the header value, a [200 OK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpstatuscode.aspx) response is returned as usual. Otherwise, a [304 NotModified](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpstatuscode.aspx) response is returned, indicating that the remote file has not been modified since the header value.

Note that a 304 NotModified response causes a [WebException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexception.aspx) to be thrown.
See: [Using If-Modified-Since in HTTP Requests](http://code.logos.com/blog/2009/06/using_if-modified-since_in_http_requests.html).

Comment: Make sure times are comparable. Use UTC.

Comment: This is probably a better answer than the link I attached.  The one I referenced dealt with the eTag.

Comment: RFC2616 http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html, sec. 14.25. "Note: When handling an If-Modified-Since header field, some servers will use an exact date comparison function, rather than a less-than function, for deciding whether to send a 304 (NotModified) response. To get best results when sending an If-Modified-Since header field for cache validation, clients are advised to use the exact date string received in a previous Last-Modified header field whenever possible." In other words, if the date you pass is AFTER the server's date, it might not return 304.